# ASP Control unordered list UL with nested list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried Menu, TreeView, BulletedList, Repeater, HtmlGenericControl but without result.

What I would like to have is asp control which render something:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For example menu it's render SPAN no UL.

```
<asp:Menu runat="server">
     <Items>
          <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 1" />
          <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 2">
             <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 2.1" />
          </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

I also tried

```
<asp:Menu RenderingMode="MenuRenderingMode" />
```

But it's not working. I'm using ASP.NET 3.5.

I need create dynamic ul list and after click on item it will check in db if exist nested items and add them to clicked list as nested ul.

I cant render whole menu at once because of performence.

Sorry if I'm not very clear.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested repeaters:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFoo" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFoo_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
     <ul>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <li>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkFoo" runat="server" />
           <asp:Repeater ID="rptBar" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptBar_ItemDataBound">
               <HeaderTemplate>
                  <ul>
               </HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnkBar" runat="server" /></li>
               </ItemTemplate> 
               <FooterTemplate>
                  </ul>
               </FooterTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
      </li>
   </ItemTemplate> 
   <FooterTemplate>
     </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then in the `ItemDataBound` handler, you need to check whether each top level item has child elements, if it does, assign those elements to the sub repeater and databind, else hide it.

```
protected void rptFoo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        FooType obj = (FooType)e.Item.DataItem;
        Repeater rptBar = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptBar");
        if(obj.Children.Count() > 0)
        {
            rptBar.DataSource = obj.Children;
            rptBar.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            rptBar.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need access to the `ul` and `li` elements from codebehind you can easily add a `runat="server"` attribute to them. The `id` attribute is necessary in order to be able to reference a single element:

```
<ul id="mainMenu" runat="server">
    <li id="mainMenuItem1" runat="server"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li id="mainMenuItem2" runat="server"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul id="subMenu" runat="server">
            <li id="subMenuItem1" runat="server"><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This structure could also be build from codebehind using `HtmlGenericControl`s.

Another option could be to use user controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx